# analogRead function not working in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, arduino-uno

I am new to Arduino and I am trying to control it through MATLAB. I have downloaded the arduino IO package and installed it.I am using MATLAB 2014a.I have a LED and I change its brightness by changing the PWM voltage as follows :

```
a=arduino('COM3');
brightness_step = (5-0)/20;
   for i = 1:20
      writePWMVoltage(a, 11, i*brightness_step);
      val=a.analogRead(0);
      display(val)
      pause(0.1);
   end

   for i = 1:20
      writePWMVoltage(a, 11, 5-i*brightness_step);
      val=a.analogRead(0);
      display(val)
      pause(0.1);
   end
clear a
```

Everything works great except for the analogRead part which throws the following error :
**No appropriate method, property, or field analogRead for class arduino.**

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have documentation or the source code for the arduino class you are using? In line 1 you instantiate an instance of a class called arduino. Your code expects that class to have a method called analogRead, and it doesn't.

Comment: But that is what it seems to be done in the slides here : http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/27843-arduino-io-package--slides-and-examples

Comment: Did you set the pinMode to analog output/input?

Comment: I actually made it by writing val=readVoltage(a,0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can try to use `fscanf()` like in the following [example](http://allaboutee.com/2011/07/04/how-to-send-data-from-the-arduino-to-matlab/) from AllAboutEE.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with the analogRead when I connected my ArduinoUno R3.

After an hour's struggle, I changed to `readVoltage`, as Controller replied in 2014, and it works perfectly.